# Excel - Refer to same cell above for two spaces, increment cell reference by 1, repeat pattern

Tags: excel

This is a weird incrementing problem, and I've tried switching to R1C1 cell referencing but Excel doesn't recognize formulas to refer to those cells so I'm back.

So say I've got cell C2800, and I need this to be =C1109. Next, I need cell C2801 to also =C1109. I then need this pattern to repeat as I drag. Something like this

```
=C1109
=C1109
=C1110
=C1110
=C1111
=C1111
...
```

I've tried the drag down straight but excel thinks this is a flat cell incrementer and simply adds 1 each movement. So essentially I need a formula for a cell refer to a position 1691 spots directly above, and then 1692 spots directly above, then 1691, then 1692, continue and repeat. Let me know if any of you know how to make this feasible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use INDEX():

```
=INDEX(C:C,INT((ROW(1:1)-1)/2)+1109)
```

Where `/2` is the repetition wanted and the `+1109` is the starting row.

Comment: Almost beat you but I've been messing up syntax lately and thought I should double check.

Comment: @Jeeped I had to think it over a few time myself.   I almost did MOD().

Comment: Beautiful! I was trying to adjust the index methods I found for incrementing over columns and I didn't understand the workings of them enough. If you have time, could you explain what's happening inside that index movement?

Regardless, thank you so much for this!

Comment: Put `=(ROW(1:1)-1)/2` into an unused cell and fill down several rows. Now add that result to 1109 and you get the value for that row in column C (i.e. C:C). Really, this is just early grade school maths but using the correct worksheet functions.